# Inspired by "by category" and came up with "by meal"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

I learned **by category** from the table below.

[image]

Is it correct to use "by meal" for the pie charts below? If it is correct, can you explain why it is "by meal" and "by category", not "by meals" and "by categories"?

> The charts show average consumption of sodium, saturated fats and
> added sugars **by meal** in the USA.

[image]

Comment: The word 'typic' is wrong; it should be 'typical'.

Comment: This is a context where usage has shifted over time. As [this chart shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=listed+by+type%2Clisted+by+types&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3), a century ago people were as likely to *list by **types*** as to *list by **type***. If it helps you to remember the current "preferred" usage, you can classify the modern singular form as more "logical" (each entry in such a list / table is for a *single* type). But that's potentially misleading, in that it implies Anglophones weren't very logical a century ago, which is nonsense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your sentence is correct. In this case, **"by"** means [according to](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/by%20)

Here are some examples used by the [scientific community:](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22by+meal%22&btnG=)

Baranowski, Tom, et al. "Patterns in children's fruit and vegetable consumption **by meal and day of the week**." Journal of the American College of Nutrition 16.3 (1997): 216-223.

Savory, C. J., and J. S. Mann. "Stereotyped pecking after feeding by restricted-fed fowls is influenced **by meal size**." Applied Animal Behaviour Science 62.2-3 (1999): 209-217.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain why it is **by meal** and not **by meals**? Can you share the links to the two examples you provided? I want to see the charts.

Comment: by meal (singular) because you are referring to the average for **each** meal.