# What does "average" mean in the charts?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I accidentally learned in [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327385/inspired-by-by-category-and-came-up-with-by-meal) (in the comment section of the chosen answer)that "average" means average consumption **per meal**. But after reading the comments in this question, I realized that "average" doesn't mean "per meal". So now my question is how they get the averages? They divided the totals by the number of what?

> The charts below show the **average** percentages in typical meals of
> three types of nutrients, all of which may be unhealthy if eaten too
> much. (This is the original introductory text of the charts.)

[image]

Comment: You can't answer that from this information.

Comment: @WendyG, thank you. I can't even answer whether **average** means consumption **per meal**?

Comment: In practice, it's hard to imagine how millions of individual meals could be analysed. It is far more likely that the figures are for typical meals, using the sales data of mainly packaged and frozen foods, the ingredients of which can be measured.

Comment: @RonaldSole, thank you. By "it's hard to imagine how millions of individual meals could be analysed", do you mean "average" doesn't mean "per meal"?

Comment: average means: average percentages of A, B and C in a typical meal. But they used the plural meals which doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Lambie, thanks you. Does "in a typical meal" in your comment means "per meal"?

Comment: Well, let's see: A typical meals consists of A, B and C. can be expressed as: typical meals consist of A, B and C. Same thing.

Comment: Can you add a link to the question where you picked up that *"average means average consumption per meal*? Average can mean a lot of things in a lot of different contexts

Comment: @Lambie, by saying "a typic meal" and "typical meals" are the same thing, do you mean that "average" doesn't mean "per meal"? I really don't understand what you mean. (The link has been added in the question.)

Comment: Average is always average re numbers. It means you take all the numbers and find their average.

Comment: I mean that in English a typical meal and typical meals can be used to refer to a general idea. A typical meal consists of rice, beans and fried bananas. Typical means consist of rice, beans and fried bananas. Same thing.

Comment: Thanks again, @Lambie. So they get the averages by dividing the totals by the number of what? Can we know this from the charts?

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. It *is* meaningful to quantify average percentages of salt / fat / sugar in each of the 4 different categories (breakfast, lunch, dinner, snacks), giving a total of 12 actual values (presented in whatever way seems suitable). But what would it mean to say you'd like those values broken down ***by person**?* You'd need to show a separate pie-chart (pun intended! :) for each person whose consumption pattern contributed to the dataset being analysed. And even then, I suggest "breakdown by person" is an almost meaningless concept.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, you're right. I changed my question. Could you take a look?

Comment: average consumption per meal would obviously refer to consumption per meal by a person.

Comment: Looks like an opinion disguised as statistics.  Without an associated breakdown of what items are considered *typical* the chart is light on information.  Apparently dinner is saltier than breakfast.   What is a typical breakfast? Ham and hash browns or avocado toast and tangerine slices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the data is correct, or could reasonably have been collected, is not clear.

The word "averge" in context means the following.

Start with sodium. It is saying that, if you gather up a bunch of typical meals in the four categories, total up the sodium from each type of meal, then get the percentage that comes from snacks it will be 14%.

That is, it is trying to tell you that if you ate breakfast, lunch, dinner, and snacks, on average 14% of the sodium would come from snacks. If you want to cut sodium then snacks are 14% of the total.

It is a fairly poor way to report it because it is reporting some kind of "typical" meal instead of the content of items in those meals. For example, snacks could be a huge variety of food. And the sodium content will be drastically different among those foods. If you snack on salty snacks vs on sweets, for example, you could get a lot of sodium in one and very little in the other.